# Word 2010 ActiveX control forms - formatting issues

Tags: vba, ms-word, formatting, activex

Hopefully a quick one

I am creating a form in Word with a Save macro that uses an ActiveX Label as a button. The label works fine as a button but I am having 2 issues:

1. when using the document in normal mode, the coding text in curly brackets for the label is still visible - see image

[image]

How do I get rid of this?

2. When printing the form, the button pushes the header text down a line:

[image]

You can see in the first picture that there is no gap here.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Press Alt+F9 to toggle off display of field codes (and make sure you're not in Design Mode).

(2) is impossible to be sure without having the document in front of me but...

Printing problems are notorious with ActiveX controls, which were designed for use with UserForms, not for the document surface. Your best bet for stability would be to use a one-row, two-column table with the button on the left and the address on the right.

Or use a MacroButton field code instead of an ActiveX control.

Comment: Thanks Cindy. 1 was exactly what I needed. With 2 I found that you can modify the layout using Format Controls when you right-click the object in Developer Mode.